# Wordpress timezone issue with woocommerce subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timezone, stripe-payments

I have a wordpress site with **woocommerce subscription** with **Stripe Payment Gateway**, I everything are working fine except a timezone issue(I think so).

I have set the wordpress **Timezone** to **UTC-4** for my current timezone in New York. But when anyone register into my site between 2000 and 2400 hrs, the registration date will changed to next date. I think it because of **UTC-4**, so Its make me confuse because between these specified hrs saved dates and displayed dates is dfferent.

**DB Saved date show: 2014-08-27 00:12:30**

**Woocommerce subscription date show: 2014-08-26 20:12:30**

The second one match with my local time, its fine, but the problem is my all payments done only in **Thursday** (in a week), The first payment is working fine, after the first payment (or after checkout) the next date is automatically set to upcoming **Thursday**,  when system automatically set the next payment date (will be after 1 week), it set the next date to after 2 weeks.

So I make the **Timezone** back to **UTC+0** (default).Frankly may be I don't know the exact problem, if so please rectify me. I don't know how to solve these automatic set next date issue by system. Can any one save me please?

I'm attaching two scenario of my subscription page..

**timezone set to UTC+0)**

[image]

**timezone set to UTC-4**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that you "set the wordpress timezone to UTC-4"?  UTC-4 is an offset, not a timezone.  You may have set it for `America/New_York`, which is normally UTC-5 but is UTC-4 when DST is in effect.  Read "Time zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Also, you need to show some code related to what you're asking if you expect a good response here on StackOverflow.  Otherwise, consider asking on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: HI @MattJohnson, Thanks for your response. I'm updating my question with some scenario for your better understand. Please review and save me...Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is off-topic. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You seem to be asking about how WordPress handles things, not about something you coded yourself. If you need to change WordPress's behavior, [ask WordPress support](http://wordpress.org/support/). If you just need help understanding the behavior of WordPress and how to configure it for your scenarios, ask [ask WordPress support](http://wordpress.org/support/), or ask on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). If your question is indeed about coding, edit the question to show your code.

Comment: I'm following this. how did you solved your issue?

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress always saves the datetime in UTC timezone.Basically if you change the php timezone then also wordpress saves in UTC timezone.I tried by changing the timezone in php.ini.But not working.I think this is the default feature of wordpress and we cant change it.If we want to change then we need to edit the wordpress core files, may be , not sure..
If anyone knows how to make the local time as default time for wordpress app,then please let us know.